# How would I read JSON data in an array using SwiftyJSON?

Tags: ios, json, uitableview, swifty-json

I have just been introduced to using JSON data in my iOS app. I used a service to parse JSON data from a website, and I would like to decode that data to display to my user in a `UITableView`. My JSON data looks as follows:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "outputScenario": "Default",
  "data": {
    "collection": [
      {
        "teamName": "Gulf Coast Monarchs, FL",
        "teamW": "10",
        "teamL": "0",
        "teamT": "0",
        "teamPct": "1.000",
        "teamGB": "-",
        "teamGP": "10",
        "teamRA": "10",
        "teamDivision": "10-0-0"
      },
      {
        "teamName": "Ohio Nationals, OH",
        "teamW": "9",
        "teamL": "1",
        "teamT": "0",
        "teamPct": ".900",
        "teamGB": "1.0",
        "teamGP": "10",
        "teamRA": "20",
        "teamDivision": "9-1-0"
      },      {
        "teamName": "Mount Kisco Chiefs, NY",
        "teamW": "0",
        "teamL": "8",
        "teamT": "0",
        "teamPct": ".000",
        "teamGB": "8.0",
        "teamGP": "8",
        "teamRA": "108",
        "teamDivision": "0-8-0"
      }
      {
        "teamName": "Mount Kisco Chiefs, NY",
        "teamW": "0",
        "teamL": "8",
        "teamT": "0",
        "teamPct": ".000",
        "teamGB": "8.0",
        "teamGP": "8",
        "teamRA": "108",
        "teamDivision": "0-8-0"
      }
    ]
  },
```

Just keep in mind that I have cut out a significant amount of the data provided in the JSON so it is easily viewable.

I would like to decode this data using SwiftyJSON if possible so I can display it to my user in a `UITableView`. For now, the UITableView will display the `team name` in the `UITableView.textLabel.text` and the `teamW` and `teamL` in the `UITableView.detailTextLabel.text`. How would I decode this data using SwiftyJSON? I am struggling to figure out how this type of structure would be decoded. I would like to use the model that I have created:

```
struct Standing: Decodable {

var teamName: String
var teamW: Int
var teamL: Int
var teamT: Int
var teamPct: Int
teamGB: Int
teamGP: Int
teamRA: Int
teamDivision: String

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to use `SwiftyJSON` as you already adopted `Decodable`?

The types in your struct are widely wrong because all values are `String`. And you need two other structs for the parent objects.

```
struct Root: Decodable {
    let success : Bool
    let outputScenario : String
    let data : TeamData
}

struct TeamData: Decodable {
    let collection : [Standing]
}

struct Standing: Decodable {
    let teamName, teamW, teamL, teamT: String
    let teamPct, teamGB, teamGP, teamRA: String
    let teamDivision: String
}
```

Decode the data, the `Standing` array is in the variable `standings`.

```
do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
    let standings = result.data.collection
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: OK, everything is working perfectly after making those significant changes. I think I was having a hard time understanding the format of the JSON, and my implementation was poor. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `Decodable`, you don't need to use `SwiftyJSON` at all, everything's built into Swift itself.

Use this as your model struct:

```
struct Standing: Codable {
    let success: Bool
    let outputScenario: String
    let data: DataClass
}

struct DataClass: Codable {
    let collection: [Collection]
}

struct Collection: Codable {
    let teamName, teamW, teamL, teamT: String
    let teamPct, teamGB, teamGP, teamRA: String
    let teamDivision: String
}
```

and parse it like so:

```
do {
  let standing = try JSONDecoder().decode(Standing.self, from: data)
} catch {
  print(error)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Along with vadian's answer, I was able to properly structure my code. Everything is working as it should now.